# Spring boot throws 403 for Mobile requests even when csrf is disabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I have a simple Spring boot application that has a POST rest api method to register users. This works perfectly when I test it through Postman. But when I test it from my Mobile application, this always throws a 403. This fails in the Options level as I don't see my backend logging an attempted request.

The usual solution given everywhere for this problem is to disable `csrf` in the spring security configuration. The funny thing is, I have this disabled and still getting a 403. I have searched as much as I could but cannot find a solution as to how this is still failing. Appreciate any help anyone could provide.

Here is the security configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // Some beans that are not relevant

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

I think it's also worth mentioning that I also tried adding `cors` disable option as advised in many other threads, to no avail.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

This is how my controller look like

```
@RestController
public class AuthenticationResource {

    // Wiring and other methods

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerNewUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserRegistrationRequest request) {
        if (!request.getConfirmPassword().equals(request.getPassword())) {
            throw new MyException(ErrorUtil.generateErrorFieldsValue("password", "confirmPassword"),
                    "Passwords do not match!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        UserAccountResponse savedUserAccount = userAccountService.save(request);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(savedUserAccount);
    }
}
```

Let me know if any other details are required.

Comment: Are the URLs used by the app and postman the same?

Comment: Add `org.springframework.security: DEBUG` to your logging and see what message Spring Security is telling you.

Answer (score -1):

From what I know this is related to CORS as you suggested, but by using the `http.cors()` you tell spring to look for a bean named `corsFilter()`. In my other projects this is how I solved it.

```java
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource configSource = new 
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

        // GET , POST, HEAD
        config.applyPermitDefaultValues();

        config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
        config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE);
        config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);

        configSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(configSource);
    }
```